# What are the conditions of applicability of linear regression?

Tags: regression, references

I am looking for a list of "Conditions of applicability of linear regression" to finish a work, but I cannot find any reference of this in any book.

I founded something in several links, but in one of this the conditions are 5, in another 4, in another 10, so I am not sure what are the correct list of "Conditions of applicability of linear regression"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the below are the assumptions of linear regression-
- Error should be normally distributed with mean zero and constant variance
Which means the residual should be randomly distributed without any particular pattern.
If there is any pattern in the error , that might be because of non linear data.
-Error should be independent.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, Manisha.  You might enjoy reading the duplicate thread because it discusses the assumptions you haven't listed.